# Is pagelink with a zone possible

Tags: tapestry

Is there a way I can direct the pagelink component that can be tied to a zone. I tried using eventlink and delegate to return the instance of an injected page. This works, but I have a dynamic number of pages in a loop for a tab component. I would just like to specify in the link where the page should be loading.

So ideally I want a pagelink with a target div.

Here is what I tried. Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
<t:loop source="tabList" value="label" index="tabNum">
        <li class="${active}">
            <t:eventlink context="label" class="no-text-decoration tapestry-tab-select" zone="tabZone"
                         event="onTabClick">
                ${label}
            </t:eventlink>
        </li>
    </t:loop>
<div class="tab-content">
    <t:zone t:id="tabZone" id="tabZone">
        <t:delegate to="tabMarkup"/>
    </t:zone>
</div>
```

and

```
@InjectPage
private TestPage testPage;

@OnEvent(value = "onTabClick")
void onTabClick(String tabLabel) {
    currentLabel = tabLabel;
    if (request.isXHR()) {
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(tabZone);
    }
}

public Object getTabMarkup() {
    testPage.onActivate(currentLabel);
    return testPage;
}
```

Comment: Do they have to be pages? Pages are not supposed to be part of another page. I think you should define Block items for each tab content and return the specific Block based on the context in the eventlink. You can define the tab contents in components if you want to use them elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @NathanQ That's what I ended up doing. It's still a little hard for me to understand why we can't embed pages within pages. It feels a little arbitrary. The way I see it I can't render pages using ajax. They have to be components. Or resort to using frames.